# Hybrid Http adapter not running on real device(Android) Mobilefirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I tried the following example: http:// mytechbook-praba.blogspot.com/2014/01/overview-installation-ibm-worklight.html

For the adapter invocation and running on the android emulator. It works fine after changing the host name from localhost to the ip address of my machine in the worklight development server in the eclipse environment.

To change the IP address of the MobileFirst server for your Android app i followed the steps of this solution: [Change IP address to run MobileFirst Android app on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883392/change-ip-address-to-run-mobilefirst-android-app-on-real-device?rq=1)

When testing it on a real android device. It fails. 
Here you can find the logcat below:
[Click here to view the logcat](http://mfpreader.comze.com/logcat6.html)

Answer (score 0):

How is this different from your previous question?

The connection attempt goes here: http://10.0.0.3:10080/AdapterProject/authorization/v1/clients/instance

You were asked to see if you are able to load the MobileFirst Console from your device's browser. Can you? The address would be: http://10.0.0.3:10080/worklightconsole

Other things you can verify: whether the device is connected to the same WiFi network as the computer that the server is running on.

Comment: while load the MobileFirst Console from your device's browser-Failed.
the device is connected to the same WiFi network as the computer that the server is running on.

Comment: I tried on other android devices with different networks. Same error.

Comment: did you  start with  packet capture while running your android port scanner app (what is going on on the network?) with filter: ip.addr=10.0.0.3 ?